# Event when Remote Client is accessing Windows 10 IoT Core?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to create a sort of lockout functionality for Windows 10 IoT Core so it can be used on a local display as well as by the Windows 10 IoT Remote Client. And when the Remote Client is in use some functionality can't be used on the local display.

To do this I am just looking for a way to detect if the Remote Client is active or an event that fires when remote client begins and stops that I can use in the UWP code to be able to implement this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to monitor if there is a connectivity of the Remote Client. It seems that the port for Remote Client is 8000. You can use `netstat` command to confirm the port. [ControlChannelTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.controlchanneltrigger) enables real time notifications to be received in the background for objects that establish a TCP connection. You may refer to this [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ControlChannelTrigger-HTTP-9d7a6b3d).